# Install Arch Linux without overriding MBR

Tags: system-installation

In my PC I have Linux mint XFCE & Windows XP professional. I intend to replace Windows XP with Arch-Linux. But I don't want to override Linux Mint MBR, I want to boot into Arch-Linux using `sudo update-grub` from Linux mint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should just work, if you tell Arch-Linux not to write the MBR. Linux Mint should see the new partition and write the new boot menu, replacing the Windows XP entry with Arch Linux.

You can be more safe by first saving the boot record under Mint

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/boot/MBR.img bs=512 count=1
```